# Consuming api with Retrofit, cannot show an element list

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I want to show a country list (only the name) but i don't know how. So i have a very long list of countries with aditional information and i only want to show the name of the countries in the list.

The MainActivity:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ICountryService.ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().create()))
                .build();

        ICountryService service = retrofit.create(ICountryService.class);

        Call<List<Country>> call = service.getCountry();


        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Country>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<Country>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    List<Country> countryList = response.body();
                    ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countryList);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }
```

The interface:

```
public interface ICountryService {

    String ENDPOINT = "https://restcountries.eu";


    @GET("/rest/v1/all")
    Call<List<Country>> getCountry();

}
```

Country calss is too long to show but i will paste only the part of the element i want to call.

```
public class Country {

    /**
     * 
     * (Required)
     * 
     */
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
```

Comment: Did you try to debug what you are getting as `response.body()`? Have you overidden `toString` in `Country` class.

Comment: Ok, thanks! i have changed the integers by Floats and it works. But now i have a long list of countries with aditional information and i want only to show the name of the countries.